# Is there a way to get package checksum using `zypper`?

Tags: package-management, opensuse, suse, checksum, zypper

How to get the checksum of the package when using `zypper`. I tried even the `--xmlout` option of `zypper` as

`zypper --xmlout --no-refresh install -D -y --no-recommends MozillaFirefox`.

Is there a way to get the checksum of the package to be installed before downloading it?

Answer (score 0):

It is in metadata xml files, but it looks zypper is not able to show it to users.

If your repos are refreshed - you can workaround by looking into those xml files, something like this:

```
> for f in /var/cache/zypp/raw/*/repodata/*primary* ; do (xzgrep -E -B10 'location href="x86_64/MozillaFirefox-[0-9]+' $f | grep -E '\^|name="MozillaFirefox"|checksum') && echo "^ $f" ; done
```

For me output is:

```
  <name>MozillaFirefox</name>
  <checksum type="sha256" pkgid="YES">a285cd0ed6a5728b231291566d308020cda73ec4a6636ced8206fb9b436b49aa</checksum>
^ /var/cache/zypp/raw/download.opensuse.org-oss/repodata/b522c46b239f38e2d4b45b461c0f943c2e855088ca844a12e6f55edf23e4b636-primary.xml.gz
```

You can download those *primary.xml.gz files as well if you are in different environment.

Another way is to look checksum in metadata on download.opensuse.org , e.g. for Leap 15.4 click on size at corresponding row at

> `https://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/15.4/sle/x86_64/?P=*MozillaFirefox*`

, it will show "SHA-256 Hash" which should match the checksum from metadata.

The problem here is that it may be a challenge for a regular user to use such workarounds, so the simplest will be download the package and calculate checksum. Or request the feature from zypper.

E.g. request zypper to provide checksums if verbosity level is above 1 e.g. for command

```
zypper se -vv MozillaFirefox
```